# Gitlab-CI DinD will not start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use DinD (Docker in Docker) with my Gitlab-CI build script and I keep getting the same error not matter what I change. What am I doing wrong?

**Errors**

```
Service container logs: 
2018-08-21T22:54:00.129660274Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2018-08-21T22:54:00.129701426Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2018-08-21T22:54:00.129706380Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2018-08-21T22:54:00.130334774Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
...
$ docker info
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.38/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
django_build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker info
  script:
    - echo "Building something."
```

**gitlab-runner config.toml**

```
concurrent = 1 
check_interval = 0 

[[runners]]
  name = "###"
  url = "###"
  token = "###"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:3.4"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

**/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

---**EDIT**---

For anyone that comes back to look at this here's how I got it working. I was running the gitlab-runner on my local machine to test things before committing to the repo.

When running the command:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker django_build
```

for whatever reason it wasn't using my config file. I found this link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1791 stating that you have to out **--docker-privileged** in the command.

After running:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged django_build
```

everything worked.

Comment: Did you restart gitlab-runner after setting privileged=true?

Comment: @Rickkwa Yes. systemctl restart gitlab-runner.service

Comment: docker host is set in config.toml using the [host](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) variable

Answer (score 3):

Double-check the [GitLab runner parameters when running docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html).

In particular, do make sure the `gitlab-runner` user is added to docker group:

sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner

From there, `sudo -u gitlab-runner -H docker info` should work.

If not, check if the [`/etc/hosts` is mounted as a volume, as in this bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3755).

---

The official [gitlab-runner documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor) states, for DiD executor, to create a config.toml with

```
[[runners]]
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = TOKEN
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
```

But the OP has found the `privileged = true` is not used.
Unless maybe if the config.tml was created by a `sudo gitlab-runner register -n... --docker-privileged` command.

If not, `gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged` is needed.

Comment: The gitlab-runner is in the docker group. The docker info command you mentioned works on the host machine but **docker info** still gives me an error inside the container.

Comment: 'sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner' worked for me, thank you!